# how to scroll div vertical scroll bar on the basis of select box select item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As requirement i need Horizontal and vertical scroll bars in select box.after research i found that select doesn't support horizontal scroll bar.so that i Wrap the SELECT inside a DIV.

```
<style type="text/css">
 .scrollable{
   overflow: auto;
   width: 70px; /* adjust this width depending to amount of text to display */
   height: 80px; /* adjust height depending on number of options to display */
   border: 1px silver solid;
 }
 .scrollable select{
   border: none;
 }
</style>

<div class="scrollable" id="scrolldiv">
<select size="6" multiple="multiple" id="selectbox">
    <option value="1" selected>option 1 The Long Option</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3">option 3</option>
    <option value="4">option 4</option>
    <option value="5">option 5 Another Longer than the Long Option ;)</option>
    <option value="6">option 6</option>
</select>
</div>
```

when the select box item grow,and you want to select item from bottom of select,div vertical scroll bar don't move the select item.

please help me,how can move the vertical scroll bar of div with item selected in select-box.

Thanks

Comment: This is different question.

Comment: Yes sorry for the mistake, i inversed vertical and horizontal !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code work for me.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
    {

    $('#selectbox').change(function()
    {
     var divscrollvalue = ( parseInt(this.selectedIndex))*17;
     $('#scrolldiv').scrollTop(divscrollvalue );

    });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `CSS` to set the font size of your option items and then use the `jQuery`'s `change()` method in conjunction with `scrollTop()` . I believe this is what you need:

Update the style

```
.scrollable select {
    font-size: 14px;
    border: none;
}
```

Add the following `jQuery`

```
$("select").change(function () {
  $("select option:selected").each(function () {
    $("#scrolldiv").scrollTop($(this)[0].index*14);
  });
});
```

The `jsFiddle` link is here: http://jsfiddle.net/jKZ5s/1/.